# Hello, how to i solve this sqlalchemy passing URI error?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

hello how can i solve this error.I have tried different answers provided for this error and it's still not working.
I am getting this error:

```
ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'api.db'
```

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restless import APIManager
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///api.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    items = db.relationship('Item', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')


class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you changed the name of your DB since first creating it? Assuming there isn't anything important in your Database and you are just testing, deleting the `.db` file and re-run the program.

Comment: No i have not changed the name. I have created another database the restarted my IDE and when i did from app import db and db.create_all() it seems to be working fine since it has created the two tables user and Item. Thanks.